# Rerun previous command under sudo

Tags: command-line, zsh

I want to be able to run a command, it fails cause it doesn't have proper permissions. Then I can write "please" to sudo the command I just ran.

Here's what I want to do in the terminal:

```
$ run command
"you don't have access to do that"
$ please
"ran successfully"
```

I saw that `!!` will grab the previous command, so I thought I could use that, but I can't get it to work.

my please.sh shell script looks like this, but I can't get any of these to work. It just says "command not found !!" and prints out the sudo usage.

```
#!/bin/zsh

#sudo !!
#sudo `!!`
sudo $(!!)
```

Comment: Does it work without the script?  If you just run `sudo !!` does it run as expected?

I think !! may just be a bash alias, so it may not work in zsh

Comment: AFAIK, history expansion (`!!` and others) only works in interactive shells and not in scripts.

Comment: `sudo !!` in interactive mode almost works as expected. when I pressed enter it would replace `!!` with the previous command. then i had to press enter again to run it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `!!` in a shell script, as you cannot access the parent shell in a child shell. Though I recommend using `sudo !!`, if you really want to make a BASH script, you would have to use .bash_history, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo `cat $HOME/.bash_history | tail -n1`
```

It is definitely NOT a perfect solution, but it should do the trick. <s>If you are using ZSH, this will not work, as ZSH does not output to .bash_history (of my knowledge).</s> **UPDATE**: Here is a version that should work with ZSH:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
. $HOME/.zshrc
sudo `cat \`readlink -f $HISTFILE\` | tail -n1`
```

Hope this helps!

If you don't understand the script, it simply runs the last command entered in BASH with sudo.

Comment: ok. I'm using zsh though. is there any equivalent for .bash_history in zsh?

Comment: Now that I look, yes, there is a version that should work. I haven't tested it yet though.

Comment: Don't read the bash history file directly. Use the `fc` or `history` built-ins. By default, the $HISTFILE is not updated until you log out of bash.

Answer (score 35):

Add to your .zshrc:

```
alias please='sudo $(fc -ln -1)'
```

Comment: Works a treat, seems better than above accepted answer for ease of use.

Comment: For the curious: `fc` stands for fix command.  The documentation is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html).

Comment: Thank you! I know this is AskUbuntu, but I used this on OSX to copy my last command to the system clipboard: `alias lastcmd="fc -ln -1 | pbcopy"` I believe this should (?) work on Ubuntu: `alias lastcmd="fc -ln -1 | xclip -selection clipboard`.

Comment: Note that if the previous command you are rerunning contained an alias, you may have to define that alias in `.zshenv` so that it is available in the subshell.